# date/strftime format with language strings | PHP

Tags: php, parsing, date, localization, strftime

I need a solution that can parse a date string but replaced with a language string of different languages, e.g.

**English**

```
$lang['day']['monday'] = 'Monday';
$lang['day']['tuesday'] = 'Tuesday';
$lang['day']['wednesday'] = 'Wednesday';
// and so on...

$lang['month']['january'] = 'January';
$lang['month']['february'] = 'February';
$lang['month']['april'] = 'April';
// and so on...
```

I need the language string to be passed through a date/strftime function, but not only English will be passed along but other languages too (when they are selected). So if a different language is selected, the language strings will be changed into the selected language. For example, French:

```
$lang['day']['monday'] = 'Lundi';
$lang['day']['tuesday'] = 'Mardi';
$lang['day']['wednesday'] = 'Mercredi';
// and so on...

$lang['month']['january'] = 'Janvier';
$lang['month']['february'] = 'Février';
$lang['month']['april'] = 'Avril';
```

So when using a format like this: `date('l dS F Y - g:iA')` it should parse like this:

```
Mardi 11th Avril 2011 - 12:22PM
```

I'm not using `setlocale` for this, because I have custom language strings, so I'm in the need for something *very* different from using `setlocale` and parsing with selected language strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use `str_replace()` on the string returned using the English to Other Language mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Zend uses language xml files with their [Zend_Date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.html) classes. This is a good solution to the problem you are facing. Another option is doing it yourself.